# Split the string in HTML tag and put them in different columns VBA

Tags: vba

I have a following data in html

```
    ....
   35.25 65.45 Car        0.2584  0.2587  0.2413  0.8956   8456  4512
     556 45.23            IN      1.3696  4.2384  9.2475   4657  4732
```

I need to get the values in 8 columns and same row.

Comment: Please show us what you have done first.

Comment: I have tried to use regular expressions. But I would want to see if we can do it using string and array operations, that will make it easy to uderstand

Comment: Please edit the question and add HTML content sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Macro recorder will come in very helpful here.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```